# Include images in typescript dist directory

Tags: typescript, image, npm, google-chrome-extension

How can I include images in my Typescript project?

If I just include the files or directory in tsconfig.json, that doesn't work.

```
  "include": [
    "src/resources/**/*.png", // <- 
    "src/**/*.json",
    "**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*"
  ]
```

The images in dist folder isn't appearing.

[image where I want the images directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGHc2.png)

I'm tried to include file by file in tsconfig.json. Or created a .ts file instead of the images file directory, but doesn't work too.

Comment: The extension icon should be placed in the same folder as manifest.json or a folder below it.

Comment: @NorioYamamoto That doesn't work, my problem isn't with the manifest configuration, but is with the compilation of typescript, that doesn't include the image files in dist folder

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the issue adding copyfiles dependence with npm

```
npm i -D copyfiles
```

And add this script in package.json

```
  "scripts": {
  "build": "tsc -p .",
  "start": "npm run build -- -w",
  "copy": "copyfiles *.png -u 2 src/resources/*.png dist/resources/", // <- this one
  "build-n-copy": "tsc -p . && copyfiles *.png -u 2 src/resources/*.png dist/resources/",
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
```

[Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles) for the package

You can either use `yarn build` then `yarn copy` or just one script `yarn build-n-copy`